# Undefined index: userID error

Tags: php, authentication, userid

Upon Logging in, I have the `userID` stored in the SESSION. However when I call `updateMarkerlocations.php` it says `userID` is undefined. Not sure what I'm missing.

**login.php**

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])){

} else {
require_once("db_const.php");
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
# check connection
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
    exit();
}
 $username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * from userinfo WHERE username LIKE '{$username}' AND password LIKE '{$password}' LIMIT 1";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
if (!$result->num_rows == 1) {
    echo "<p>Invalid username/password combination</p>";
} else {
 $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

  setcookie("username", time() +60*60*24*30*365);
$_SESSION['userID'] = $row['userID']; 

     echo "<p>Logged in successfully!, Please close the window</p>";
}
}
?>
```

**updateMarkerLocations.php**

```
 <?php
include 'db_const.php';


function insertMarkerLocations()
{
$markerCount = 0;
if (isset($_POST['markerCount']))
$markerCount = $_POST['markerCount'];

if(isset($_SESSION["userID"]))
{
 $userID = $_SESSION["userID"];
}

$con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);

$userID = $_POST['userID'];

for($i=0 ; $i < $markerCount; $i++){ 
      $index = $i;
      ++$index;
      $curMarkerID = $_POST["markerID$index"];
      $curLang = $_POST["lang$index"];
      $curLat = $_POST["lat$index"];
  // Now write the current marker details in to the db.
  $query = "INSERT INTO userinfo (userID, markerID, lang, lat ) VALUES ('$userID', '$curMarkerID', '$curLang', '$curLat')";
  mysql_query($query)
    or die(mysql_error());
}
$msg = "SUCCESS";
return $msg;
}

 $msg = insertMarkerLocations();
echo json_encode($msg);
 ?>
```

Comment: You need to do `session_start()` in ALL the scripts that will be reading/setting session data, and do it BEFORE you try to access the session, and before you do any output.

Comment: Your code is **VERY** vunerable towards [SQL Injection](http://bit.ly/1n7xViV). [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**pink box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I just added session_start() but still get userID error. Something isn't working. I'm not sure where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this at the top of each file:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
```

Also, when you do:

```
$userID = $_POST['userID'];
```

you should ensure that `$_POST['userID']` exists:

```
if(isset($_POST['userID'])) $userID = $_POST['userID'];
```

Comment: Try to echo `$_SESSION['userID']` when assigning it.

Comment: echo works on login page and on the updatemarkerLocations page. So something is broken here. I don't understand why it can't find userID when the echo works

Comment: I've updated my answer. If doesn't work, tell me where is the error line.